# Telegram API: how to get contact on telegram and get status with python @TelethonUpdates

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

how to add contact with phone number and get the contact user status
 @TelethonUpdates

Comment: Please update your question with any code you have already tried.

Comment: is there a reason you put @TelethonUpdates in your question ?